# How to find out how many words are in each line?

Tags: c

Say you have a text file filled with sentences. For example:

```
hey how are you
you good?
nice to meet you jeff
```

I'm writing a program to print things out depending on how many indexes are on each line but I cant wrap my head around how to find how many words on each line. How could I go about counting how many words are on each line?

```
for (int i=0; i < wordle->leng; i++) {
    printf ("%s ", wordle->allwords[i]);
```

This is my print function for the program. `leng` is how many lines so it knows how many times to repeat.

Some of the lines have 5 words, some 3, and it isn't printing in the correct format. Also not all lines will end with punctuation.

Comment: *If* you can assume that only one space is ever used to separate words, then the number of words on a line is just the number of spaces plus 1.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem with pencil and paper?  If so, now you just write code to do the same process.

Comment: ... only one space is ever used to separate words, **and there are no spaces at the beginning or end of the line,** then the number of words ...

Comment: strtok can be used to chop a line up into works, or to count words

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function is very useful for that; it reads line from stream until EOL. So you can read with that line by line and the you could make a loop that adds 1 to `int word_count = 0;` every time you read something that is not a whitespace and the previous char before that was whitespace (but you have to make additional logic for initial word).

You can use [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) if you don't have `getline()` available, but it doesn't expand the buffer to deal with extra long lines, unlike `getline()`.